# Sprite animation cannot be play when player retry Unity

Tags: unity, animation

[image]In my unity2d game I've create a sprite animation, like a mushsroom bounce.

When I start the game for the first time the animation plays properly, but when the player dies, and retries, the animation won't play. I cannot reload the scene, I have to reset the player's transform.position.

How can I solve this problem?

```
if (target.tag == "Masroom") {
        target.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().enabled = true;
        playerRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0,8);
    }
```

Comment: Can you upload an image of your animation controller? Also, Where is your code sample from? Is it the Update method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this :

```
 if (target.tag == "Masroom") {
        target.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("MasroomBounce");
        playerRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0,8);
    }
```

What you are doing now is enabling the whole Animator component and that will play only once unless the whole scene is reloaded.

Edit: You have to create a empty state with a transition to your state  like this and then the code repeats the animation
[image]

Comment: thanks for reply ,In my game I've cannot be reload scene when player retry I've only reset player transform.position in current scene. .

Comment: Yes so use the line of code I provided for you. This will make the Animator play the state with the provided name. I will make a edit

Comment: @ Uri Popov ok. I try it.

Comment: I've try your edited code but still that issue there.

Comment: do you get any errors or warnings in the console ?

Comment: no,not give any kind of errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: @Chetan check the new edit it might help you now. Maybe watch a couple of tutorials online on how the Animator woks.

Comment: I've also try this.